# AOP pointcut expression for any public method of a service

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

What is the simplest pointcut expression that would intercept all public methods of all beans annotated with `@Service`? For instance, I expect it to affect both public methods of this bean:

```
@Service
public MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    public String doThis() {...}
    public int doThat() {...}
    protected int doThatHelper() {...} // not wrapped
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) should be extremely helpful.

I would do by creating two individual point cuts, one for all public methods, and one for all classes annotated with @Service, and then create a third one that combines the pointcut expressions of the other two.

Take a look at (***7.2.3.1 Supported Pointcut Designators***) for which designators to use.  I think you are after 'execution' designator for finding public methods, and the 'annotation' designator for finding your annotation.

Then take a look at (***7.2.3.2 Combining pointcut expressions***) for combining them.

I have provided some code below (which I have **not** tested).  It is mostly taken from the documentation.

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))") //this should work for the public pointcut
private void anyPublicOperation() {}

//@Pointcut("@annotation(Service)") this might still work, but try 'within' instead
@Pointcut("@within(Service)") //this should work for the annotation service pointcut
private void inTrading() {}

@Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && inTrading()")
private void tradingOperation() {}
```

Comment: Are these pointcuts tested? As far as I know `@annotation` doesn't define join point but collects its context. Maybe you should use `@within` instead?

Comment: I mentioned in the answer that I have not tested these pointcuts.  But I agree, the asker probably would rather use @within to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Would it not be better to amend your answer then? I think it might not work as it currently stands. I have done what the question is asking using `within` and it works, but I realise now that I should be using `@within`.

Comment: I think `within` is used when you are looking 'within' the given matcher, and `@within` is used when you are looking 'within' something annotated with the matching annotation(s).  Also, I may not have mentioned it in my previous comment, but I did indeed update the code.