# spring AOP with annotations issue

Tags: spring, annotations, aop

i have an annotation in my app

```
@Trans
```

that i would like AOP to intercept and manage the transaction for.  is there a tutorial out there that can tell me how to do this in spring 3?

Answer (score 2):

You're reinventing the `@Transactional` annotation of Spring. Read http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Answer (score 2):

If you have your own annotation called `@Trans`, or if you meant Spring's own `@Transactional` annotation, you can use the `@within` Pointcut Designator.

From [Spring's AOP documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html):

> @within - limits matching to join points within types that have the
>   given annotation (the execution of methods declared in types with the
>   given annotation when using Spring AOP)

and

> any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the
>   declared type of the target object has an @Transactional annotation:
>
> @within(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)

So using this advice, you can create a Pointcut around all methods that have the annotation you specify.

Also, this is a similar question, you may find it helpful:

[AOP pointcut expression for any public method of a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861016/aop-pointcut-expression-for-any-public-method-of-a-service/6861170#6861170)